# Eloquent Compare time

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a Model which stores the total time spent on page in, the format is HH:MM:SS, i am trying to ask the user to input time in HH:MM:SS and then I would compare the entries value to the one stored in the database.

here is my query so far but its not yeilding any results back.

`$assignees = EntryKPITable::where("total_time_inside",'>',$request->number)->whereBetween('created_at',[$from, $to])->get();`

I have searched through Eloquent module and only found "WhereDate()" which compare time+date.

all the questions i found did a comparison using DATETIME format(total time can be more than 24h in my case)

Comment: If you store the date as a unix timestamp in database, and convert the user input to one, you can thereby compare them.

Comment: @PatricNox can you elaborate more? how can when storing them in the database i am using php gmdate() function. in the database they are stored the data type is "time"